# Validation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

how to get the request object in the validator class, as i need to validate the contents ie the parameters present in the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I'm following your question correctly, but with Spring MVC, you pass the object into the method and annotate it (at least with Spring 3), like so:

```
@RequestMethod(value = "/accounts/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAccount(@ModelAttribute @Valid Account account, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "accounts/accountForm";
    }

    accountDao.save(account);
}
```

The relevant annotation here is @Valid, which is part of JSR-303. Include the BindingResult param as well so you have a way to check for errors, as illustrated above.

Answer (score 11):

You have two choices:

- JSR 303 (Bean Validation) Validators
- Spring Validators

---

For **JSR 303** you need Spring 3.0 and must annotate your Model class with JSR 303 Annotations, and write an @Valid in front of you parameter in the Web Controller Handler Method. (like [Willie Wheeler show in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576790/validation-in-spring-mvc/5576877#5576877)). Additionaly you must enable this functionality in the configuration:

```
<!-- JSR-303 support will be detected on classpath and enabled automatically -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

---

For **Spring Validators**, you need to write your Validator (see [Jigar Joshi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576790/validation-in-spring-mvc/5576883#5576883)) that implements the [org.springframework.validation.Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) Interface. The you must register your Validator in the Controller. In Spring 3.0 you can do this in a `@InitBinder` annotated Method, by using [WebDataBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html)`.setValidator` ([setValidator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setValidator%28org.springframework.validation.Validator%29) it is a method of the super class `DataBinder`)

```
Example (from the spring docu)
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processFoo(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }
}
```

For more details, have a look at the Spring reference, Chapter [5.7.4 Spring MVC 3 Validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html#validation-mvc).

*BTW: in Spring 2 there was someting like a `setValidator` property in the SimpleFormController.*

Comment: Setting spring validator hides hibernate validation feature (JSR 303). Is any way to keep hibernate validation and additionaly use own spring validator?

Comment: @Saram: I strongly recommend to use JSR 303 instead of spring validators. -- Anyway post a new question if you want to ask something.

Comment: You can use  `binder.addValidator(new FooValidator());` to combine both validation approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Using simple validator (your custom validator)
You don't need request object to get param there in Validator. You can directly have it from.

For example : This will check field from request with name `name` and `age`

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    /**
    * This Validator validates just Person instances
    */
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
}
```

**Also See**

- [Document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add another method with HttpServletRequest parameter.

```
 public void validateReq(Object target, Errors errors,HttpServletRequest request) {

       // do your validation here
}
```

Note that you are not overriding a method here

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue when i use spring validator validate captcha.
In the validator implementor, i want to get the correct-captcha from HttpSession(from HttpServletRequest get HttpSession).

Not found any good codes for get it in validator, so bad!!!

There are some compromise proposal as follow:

1. In the binding form DTO add an additional field (call: correctCaptcha), in the Controller method set the field value from HttpSession , then you can validate in the validator

   ```
   public class UserRegisterDto {
       private String correctCaptcha;
       //getter,setter
   }
   ```
2. Add the HttpServletRequest reference in the binding form DTO, then can use it in the validator.

   ```
   public class UserRegisterDto {
       private HttpServletRequest request;
       //getter ,setter
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "register.hb", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String submitRegister(@ModelAttribute("formDto") @Valid UserRegisterDto formDto, HttpServletRequest request,BindingResult result) {
       formDto.setRequest(request);
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
           return "user_register";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry, it is not work, maybe use  Spring MVC interceptor is a good solution