# How to avoid overwriting of non-null values with null values?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm using spring MVC for receiving a JSON from client and automatically create an object from it. The problem is that the client doesn't send to server all the fields that are in the entity, but some fields are null and overwrite existing values calling userDao.persist(user). For example, i have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
```

But the user never send me the password, so the object built from JSON has "password" field  empty. I don't want the password field to be overwritten by a null value. There's a way to say to hibernate "if you find a null value ignore it and don't overwrite the value that is saved in database?". I can't believe that there isn't a easy solution to this apparently simple problem.

Comment: use @jsoningnore annotation over password field

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I wrote this answer while being an unexpirienced studen. Today my answer would be similar to the one from @James DW. Also, from the term `userDao`, I assume that it is some kind of ORM/ODM. In that case it is definitly worth searching "pros and cons of ORM/ODM".

#### original answer (which was accepted back in 2011):

If your problem is only the database, then I suggest you use a stored procedure, which checks if that value is null, and then dose not change the existing value. That way you can still send a null value, and your validation is on server side which is more robust.

Comment: you mean something like:

public void update(User jsonUser) {
   User dbUser = userDao.getUserById(jsonUser.getIdApp());
   
   if(jsonUser.getName() != null)
      dbUser.setName() = jsonUser.getName();
}

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, I don't know how to use indentation in comments :-D

Comment: I think that indentations in comments are not possible. Anyway read [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx). Its a tutorial on stored procedures. In general its like a small function executed by the DB, so you can be 100% sure all your data has been checked there. Doesn't matter what language you originally use, just call that procedure, instead of calling 'insert into ....'

Comment: In some way yes. But in your stored procedure you don't deal anymore with a  what is in the JSON object, you have the separated elements. If your question is how to not update the `password` field - then its simple use `INSERT (userName, field1, ...) VALUES(...)` and just skip the password field. And I suggest you (if that is the case) to rethink your design, because you should not write all the time to the table containing the password field.

Answer (score 6):

I think the source of your problem is that the object you're getting back from your JSON parsing never had the actual values in it. It is a bean that has only the values set that are in your JSON.

You need to load your entity from the DB and then set the non-null fields from your JSON onto the loaded entity. That way only fields that are supplied in the JSON will be set.

I recommend an adapter of some sort to "merge" (not JPA merge) the DB version and the JSON version before saving the DB version.

Adding a @NotNull constraint and Bean Validation will make sure the values are not null when attempting to save. Unfortunately they won't help you get the values into the entity to save.

Comment: Yes you focus the problem.The point is that i need to know which is this "adapter of some sort to merge". Because the other way is (as you say) "set the non-null fields from your JSON onto the loaded entity" that could be very boring and inelegant to be done manually on an entity with twenty fields.

Comment: @Fabio Unfortunately we sometimes have to do the boring stuff. The idea is do it once! I suggest create a separate object (interface too) to do the merge that way you can encapsulate the merge logic. Then you can test and reuse it where you need to.

Comment: How can I do just once? Implementation of merging must be different for every entity...

Comment: @Fabio True, you will need to do the work per entity, unless you want to use reflection. Ask yourself, how many entities will I need to do this for? Is doing it once per entity (including tests) going to take you that long?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
I solved it in [this way](https://gist.github.com/paolinux79/6a50b843a6c23009db48).

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Hashtable;



public class Updater {

private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Updater.class);

public static <E> E updater(E oldEntity, E newEntity) {

    Field[] newEntityFields = newEntity.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Hashtable newHT = fieldsToHT(newEntityFields, newEntity);

    Class oldEntityClass = oldEntity.getClass();
    Field[] oldEntityFields = oldEntityClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : oldEntityFields){
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = newHT.get(field.getName());
        if (o != null){
            try {
                Field f = oldEntityClass.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
                f.setAccessible(true);
                log.info("setting " + f.getName());
                f.set(oldEntity, o);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }

    return oldEntity;
    }



private static Hashtable<String, Object> fieldsToHT(Field[] fields, Object obj){
    Hashtable<String,Object> hashtable = new Hashtable<>();
    for (Field field: fields){
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            Object retrievedObject = field.get(obj);
            if (retrievedObject != null){
                log.info("scanning " + field.getName());
                hashtable.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return hashtable;
}
}
```

It is clearly a workaround but it seems to work smoothly... in the next days I think I'll write the recursive part.

Answer (score 0):

Implement setters for you attributes and do the checks there.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Hibernate Validation](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) project, which can be used to verify your object on DAO level, as well as on [Spring Web layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576790/validation-in-spring-mvc).