# Validation Spring confusion to render error message

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, attributes, controller

I try to render error message but it's not appears:

I have validator:

```
@Component
class ValidatorFBOSSearch implements Validator {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {

        return FormBackObjectSearch.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors error) {    

        FormBackObjectSearch fbos = (FormBackObjectSearch)obj;  

        if ("".equals(fbos.particularDate)){            
            error.rejectValue("particularDate", "required.listOfDates", "This field is required");  
        }       
    }
}
```

it have to cheak does my field in backing object for form have value inputed or not. rejectValue has three param. First - looks for a value in Model Attribute in my backing object, Secong looks for error message in properties file(my properties file located in resourses/error forlder) Third param in methos says if it won't be able to find message in error properties file will render it as default, here is my sniped of code in my servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And this my xml config for messageSourse to get errors for Validator in servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- Resolves error messages for validator from /Education/src/main/webapp/resources/errors-->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="errors/errormessages"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Here peace of my controller code for dealing with requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public void search(Model model) {           
            FormBackObjectSearch fbos = new FormBackObjectSearch();
            model.addAttribute("fbosAttribute", fbos);      
        }


        @RequestMapping(value ="/result", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String extract(@RequestParam String nameOfInstitution,
                              @RequestParam String particularDate,
                              @RequestParam String typeOfInstitution,
                              @ModelAttribute("fbosAttribute") FormBackObjectSearch fbos,
                              BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
                              Model model) throws Exception {

            ValidatorFBOSSearch validatorFBOS = new ValidatorFBOSSearch();
                validatorFBOS.validate(fbos, result);

                if(result.hasErrors()) {
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fbosAttribute", fbos);    
                    return "redirect:/search";


                } else {

                    if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeOfInstitution =="") {                   
                        controllerSupportClass.findWithDateAndName(nameOfInstitution, particularDate, model);                   
                    } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeOfInstitution !="") {                    
                        controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDateAndType(typeOfInstitution, particularDate, model);                  
                    } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeOfInstitution ==""){         
                        controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDate(particularDate, model);    
                    } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeOfInstitution !="") {
                        throw new Exception("Search by choose all parameters is not exceptable");   
                    } else {    
                        throw new Exception("You didn't put any search parameters");    
                    }

                }
            return "search";
        }
```

And here is peace of my jsp:

```
<form:form action="result" method="post" modelAttribute="fbosAttribute" >

<table>

<tr>
<th>Date for extracting:</th> 
<td><form:select  path="particularDate">
<form:option value=""> -Choose date-</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfDates}"></form:options>
</form:select> <td><form:errors path="particularDate" cssClass="error"/></td>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

The problem is thet I can not see error messages show up. I tried to use Flash Attributes to have error appears after riderect, but nothing heppend. cuz I found here that when I use rederect it makes my model and errors deleted and start new one. But How can I have advantage to use flash attibutes to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing a redirect (upon validation errors) in the first place?

Comment: Yeas, thank you for your answer.. I do this because I want return user  who did not put a date in my jsp -> particularDate to do this again.. What would you suggest sir??

Comment: You should never compare strings with `==` or `!=`, instead use `equals` or `isEmpty`  (in you controller)

Comment: BTW: you should have a look at springs support for jsr303 "bean validation". Its annotation based approach is much easyer to use for simple validation, than this hand written validators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register the validator for an specific controller you need can use the `@InitBimder' annotation.

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new ValidatorFBOSSearch());
}
```

For mor details how  to register the validator see my answer at:
[Validation in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576790/validation-in-spring-mvc)

---

I think your check statement is wrong:

```
if ("".equals(fbos.particularDate)){
```

If a user enters nothing, then a String will not be empty ( `""` ), it will be `null`. Therefore use:

```
if (fbos.particularDate == null || fbos.particularDate.isEmpty())
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answers.. I cheacked before what it is return it showed me empty string like "" To make shure that it's empty I put _ and _ between and it just return _ _. That's why I put if ("".equals(fbos.particularDate)). I thought about JSR 303 too, but kinda want to implement Validator interface looks very good to get in use to it for complex apps in future. I tried also how you suggested and I know it was my mistake, but nothing changed, I just want to know the Validator trigger automaticaly? I kinda confused. Thank you.

Comment: @d.a.v. No, the validator triggers only if it is tegisteted for the controller - see my extended answer. -- next time try to prase your question as clear as you did in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I'm sorry if I complicated you