# How do I make Spring's @Validated use a custom validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

E.g. let's say I had a domain class, a custom validator, and a controller kind of like this:

```
public class MyDomain {
    /*Stuff that I want to validate*/
}

public class MyValidator extends LocalValidatorFactoryBean {
    /*Custom Validation Logic*/
}

@RestController
public class myController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/myDomain", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void doStuff(@RequestBody @Validated MyDomain myDomain){
        //Do stuff. 
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that when validation happens on `@Validated MyDomain myDomain` that `MyValidator` is used?

Also, can I use a subclass of `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean` for this or do I need to implement `org.springframework.validation.Validator`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576790/validation-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: You can use @Ralph answer to register your validator http://stackoverflow.com/a/5577093/1393484

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend using JSR 303 validation.

Comment: @chrylis I'm trying to do this because I need more than just JSR 303 validation.

Comment: What "more"? The point of JSR 303 is that it's extensible in a standardized way.

Comment: @chrylis I need to make sure that certain String values on myDomain are elements of a set of approved values. e.g. State should be "MN" and not "David"

Comment: So write a `@UsaState` validation rule, and `@Valid` will Just Work.

Comment: @chrylis, that sounds like the sort of thing I'm looking for. How exactly do I go about doing that? Can you link me to somewhere with more information? I think I may have just missed something.

Comment: Good example at https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/custom-jsr-303-bean-validation-constraints-for-the-jsr-310-new-datetime-api.html